# Raw git tree creating on win console

Tags: windows, git, cmd

I'm trying to create git tree manually in learning purpose like it's shown [here](http://alx.github.io/gitbook/7_raw_git.html). Despite all similar manuals contains examples for UNIX systems, I've tried to do similar on Windows platform.

But I'm facing issues with **git mktree** command.
As manual states, I need to send string with data to standard input (stdin) like that:

```
$ echo -e "100640 blob 03f128cf48cb203d938805e9f3e13b808d1773e9\tfile1
100640 blob b973e639605e63466ea5ba09b04a545f16946ca8\tfile2" | git-mktree
```

For win I've tried:

```
C:\Users\eduards\git_test>git mktree < echo 100640 blob 0aa895dbdf657c61805d8f9a1c6a31cb0429b305\tfile1
Не удается найти указанный файл.
```

It tolds that file can't be found. 
Then've tried the next constructrion:

```
C:\Users\eduards\git_test>git mktree < CON
100640 blob 0aa895dbdf657c61805d8f9a1c6a31cb0429b305\tfile1
fatal: input format error: 100640 blob 0aa895dbdf657c61805d8f9a1c6a31cb0429b305\tfile1?
```

Git says that something is wrong with input. So one more try with changed "\t" into Tab-symbol entered with keyboard:

```
C:\Users\eduards\git_test>git mktree < CON
100640 blob 0aa895dbdf657c61805d8f9a1c6a31cb0429b305    file1
```

Nothing happened and it still waits for any futher input after any return key clicking.

Last variant was to create separate file with mentioned string and forward it to stdin.

```
C:\Users\eduards\git_test>git mktree < someTextFile
74b758ee483920df41519ce34ac674348ccd2a68
```

**Finally** it has done what I need, but still *what were my mistakes with previous attempts*?

Answer (score 0):

The problems in your first three methods were:

#### Method 1

You cannot pass value to a command using StdIn from other command. So your attempt to pass value with echo command failed.

#### Method 2

The tab character formatting was incorrect.

#### Method 3

You have to end the StdIn by pressing Ctrl+Z and Enter.